# Handling objects states properly

Tags: unity-game-engine, design-patterns, state

I'm having troubles with proper management of objects states.

Check out the following:

```c#
class PlayerController 
{
    bool canMove = true;
    bool canRotate = true;
    bool canShoot = true;
    bool canCastAbility = true;
}

class PlayerCamera 
{
    bool canLookAround = true;
    bool followPlayer = true;
}

class PlayerAbility 
{
    when used over time - PlayerCamera.canLookAround = false;
}

class PauseScreen 
{
    when game is paused - PlayerCamera.canLookAround != PlayerCamera.canLookAround;
}
```

You might already see what's the problem here - When we are NOT using our ability and we want to pause the game, "canLookAround" will be properly set to false. Although when we are using our ability and at the same time we want to pause the game, "canLookAround" will be set to true - which is incorrect.

I believe I dont have to add that this way of managing states looks terrible and it's super easy to get lost around all of these "canDoSomething" booleans. Not only Player have that kind of booleans, a lot of scripts inside the project are affected by this kind of poor states management and it's causing a lot of frustration and this feeling of being lost.

After all you end up with some kind of abomination like this:

```c#
void PauseGame()
{
    enemy.canMove = false;
    enemy.canShoot = false;
    player.canMove = false;
    player.canShoot = false;
    player.canCastAbility = false;
    NPCs.canMove = false;
    etc...
}
```

Apart of having enumerator holding current state of an object, what would be a proper way of handling states like these ?

Is there any design pattern that handles this problem well? Is there any principle that has to be followed on the architecture level of the project in order to handle states easily?

Please share your experiences with me, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the pausing of the game is not an object related state but a global one you should tread it like that.

You shouldn't change any objects states just because you paused the game. The one who pauses the game shouldn't even (need to) know that the concept of objects exist. It is only responsible for entering and exiting the paused state!

I would rather use a global `bool` flag for the paused state itself and let all of your components check for it like e.g.

```c#
public class PauseScreen
{
    private static bool gameIsPaused;

    // ReadOnly public property so others can access the value
    // but only this class may change it
    public static bool GameIsPaused => gameIsPaused;

    void PauseGame()
    {
       gameIsPaused = true;
    }
}
```

and now let all your components depend on it. As the value is `static` you don't even need a reference for this (though you could also use a usual instanced field and property of course).

```c#
private void Update()
{
    if(PauseScreen.GameIsPaused) return;

    ....
}
```

Comment: @Jakubbodesu You can use [properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/properties) and construct queries based on internal state. I.e. `bool CanShoot { get { return CanMove && currentWeapon?.Ammo > 0; } }`

Comment: @Camile don't forget the paused state `bool CanShoot => CanMove && currentWeapon?.Ammo > 0 && PauseScreen.GameIsPaused;` ;)

Comment: @derHugo Thank you very much for your answer! What do you think about having that many "canDoSomething" states in one script? Is this normal? It looks kinda awful tbh